# Android, How to rotate a video 90 degrees, but not the SurfaceView

Tags: android

I want to rotate the video 90 degrees when it played,
and I have to keep the other things, like buttons without be rotate.
Who can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible.
You'd honestly be best off just rotating the video using a video editor and using that in my opinion.